# How to change system background color in Android application while orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have simple Android application with webView. But when I rotate the phone, strange system white background color appears as you can see on the video below:

[image]

Is there any way how to change the white background color to the black color, so the rotation will be smoother?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Still I don't get why the default settings in XML does no effect on this. I had to set it via code.